# EmberJS: is it possible to save only modified objects?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I have a small and quite standard application that:

- Fetches objects from the server
- Renders the objects and allows some editing on them. If it is important, this editing only affects `DS.hasMany` attributes.
- Offers a saving back to the server (it should not happen automatically, only on user request)

The app controller handles a `save` event, and there I store the stuff. The code looks like this:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Controller.extend({
    actions: {
        save() {
            this.store.peekAll('object').forEach(obj => {
                obj.save();
            });
        }
    }
});
```

This issues a PUT request for each object locally loaded. It works fine, but it is a little bit of brute force. Instead, I would like to save only the modified objects.

I have tried with [dirtyType](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Model.html#property_dirtyType), but it returns `undefined` inside of the `.forEach`, and also [hasDirtyAttributes](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Model.html#property_hasDirtyAttributes), but it returns `false` always.

I could build my own cache of modified objects, but that would be a lot of work and error prone. Is there any standard way of handling this situation? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This works fine:

```
if(obj.get('hasDirtyAttributes')){
  obj.save();
}
```

JSBin: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/jiqevo/1/edit?html,css,js,output

Modifying relationships does not set the model as dirty. As a workaround you can set it dirty manually, like this:

```
this.get('model').send('becomeDirty');
```

Comment: Hi, this is not what I need. I think this `isDirty` property is true when an object is not yet synchronized with the local store (i.e. is waiting for the event loop). In my case, when the user clicks on save, all objects have been locally synchronized, and `isDirty` is always false. What I need is a way to tell if an object has been locally modified since loading.

Comment: @ikaros45 No it's definitely when the object as been modified. If you do: `setTimeout(function(){if(obj.get('isDirty')){console.log("I'm dirty");}}, 1000);` the object will still be dirty i.e. it's not waiting for the eventloop.

Comment: @ikaros45 The reason why you might not see it is because ember doesn't support `isDirty` on relationships (yet). http://stackoverflow.com/a/32014670/29347

Comment: That was actually the reason. As a workaround, I have the controller set the model dirty each time the `hasMany` is changed: `this.get('model').send('becomeDirty')`. It is not completely right, because doing and undoing will leave the object dirty, but it is quite acceptable. Include this info in your answer and I will accept it :)